# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Bluetooth headset plantronics m55 shows up and disappears immediately

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, headphones, headset

I'm just switched to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and wanted to pair my Plantronics m55 bluetooth headset, but right after establishing a connection it disconnects.

[image]

These were the steps:

1. Click on bluetooth icon in the menu bar
2. Set up new devices
3. Switch on the headset
4. Headset shows up & disappears immediately